# how to proceed further this gis project?

Tags: google-maps, gis, postgis, mapserver

**For my company in house use i want to develop a gis project with simple goals.**

1. To display all places with name wherever my company presents,over the normal country map.
2. Connect main office with branch offices graphically ( by line ).
3. By clicking a place user will be directed to a new page containing information about the place.
4. add new places graphically.

**what I know/did little bit already:**

1. working with LAMP platform on Ubuntu.
2. HTML,Javascript
3. Installed mapserver and able to re produce sample maps.
4. sucessfully installed Postgresql, postgis.
5. sucessfully loaded osm data into postgresql.(by osm2pgsql utility)

**What I want to know**

1. How to display osm data in browser as like google maps.
2. how to add new places graphically
3. How to connect two places by a line in map.

many Thanks .

Comment: Looks like company-homework :)

Comment: You can also ask good people @ http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into client side frameworks like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or more full solutions like [geomajas](http://www.geomajas.org)
you will still need to setup everything but these could provide you with what you need

more libs/apps/etc on [osgeo](http://www.osgeo.org)

Comment: It is based on java, I think it gives me a long learning curve, instead if it based on LAMP platform its easy to implement. Any comment?

Comment: OpenLayers is not based on Java, but Javascript. Any reasonable solution for draggable maps in a browser will be in JavaScript. If you don't want to learn Javascript, then I would suggest you probably don't want slippy maps.

Comment: I mentioned geomajas.
yes openlayers may be the right choice.
thank you.

Comment: if you know some javascript, openlayers is for you, if you know some java, geomajas uses gwt as frontend so it's al java.